# Bounded and Lipschitz De Rham cohomology representatives for pull-backs from classifying spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, classifying-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with $\pi_1(M)=\Gamma$. Let $\tilde{M}$ be its universal cover, and let $f\colon M\to B\Gamma$ be a classifying map.

Given any smooth differential form $\omega$ on $M$, let $\|{\omega}\|_x$ denote its pointwise norm induced by $g$. Let us say that $\omega$ is

- *Bounded* if $x\mapsto \|{\omega}\|_x$ is uniformly bounded above on $M$;
- *Lipschitz* if $x\mapsto \|{\omega}\|_x$ is Lipschitz on $M$.

Clearly, if $M$ is compact, then for any class $c\in H^2(B\Gamma,\mathbb{R})$, the pull-back $f^*c$ is represented by a bounded two-form in de Rham cohomology.

**Question:** Suppose $M$ is non-compact. What conditions, if any, would one need to impose on $c$ so that $f^*c$ can be represented by a bounded (resp. Lipschitz) differential form?